# Rails test stack causing user validation to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

### Update: The first email address generated by Forgery is ALWAYS THE SAME. Subsequent ones are different, but the first one is always the same. I believe that this might be the cause of my problems.

I have been working on a problem for 3 days, trying to just bash my way through it to learn how these tests work. But I am at a loss.

I have a User model, and a `factory_girl` User factory. Looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email)      { |n| Forgery(:internet).email_address }
    sequence(:company)    { |n| Forgery(:name).company_name }
    password              "password"
    password_confirmation "password"
    active                 true   
    admin false

    trait :admin do
      admin true
    end

    trait :inactive do
      active false
    end

  end

end
```

I have a bunch of specs to run, which I run one at a time using `Guard` as I work on them. At the top of my specs I have this line:

```
let!(:user) { login_user }
```

And in `spec/support` I have a file called `login_macros.rb`, which looks like this:

```
module LoginMacros
  def login_user
    plan = FactoryGirl.create(:plan, name: "Test Multi")
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    subscription = FactoryGirl.create(:subscription, plan: plan) # Fails here
    visit login_path
    fill_in 'Email', :with => user.email
    fill_in 'Password', :with => user.password
    click_button 'Go'
    user
  end
end
```

See that line that begins with `subscription =` above? That fails with the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: let!(:user) { login_user }
 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

My `Subscription` factory looks like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :subscription do
  end
end
```

I have no idea if that factory is correct. In my app, `Subscription belongs_to User` and `Plan`. After reading the documentation I am still not clear on how I could be getting a duplicate email if I'm using the `Forgery` gem. Can anyone please help? Obviously I can't spend any more time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by forcing an upgrade to ~> 2.14.0 for `RSpec` and `rspec-rails` and following the directions found [here](http://devblog.avdi.org/2012/08/31/configuring-database_cleaner-with-rails-rspec-capybara-and-selenium/#comment-935743168).

Answer (score 1):

Your `login_user` method references `user` to specify the email value, but it's not clear where `user` is defined. I would guess that it's returning the same value on each of successive calls to this method. If it's not clear where you've defined `user`, you might want to output `defined?(user)` at the beginning of `login_user` to see what kind of object it is.

Comment: I had mistakenly deleted that line during formatting, I just added it back. Thanks for the catch.